# Updated PhpStorm and cannot open it anymore

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I updated Jetbrains Phpstorm-162.1121.38 and now I am unable to open the application.  When I try to open it from the terminal I keep getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/intellij/openapi/util/SystemInfo
at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:84)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.openapi.util.SystemInfo
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

Does anyone know what the problem is and how it could be fixed?